# Magento 2 : Which event is dispatched when a discount is applied?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, coupon, coupon-codes

I have tried already listening to **salesrule_validator_process**, **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost** and **controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost**. None of these are getting dispatched when I apply a discount coupon on the checkout page.
Here is my `/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<event name="salesrule_validator_process">
   <observer name="bt_add_coupon_from_cart" instance="BT\Connect\Observer\TrackCoupon"/>
</event>
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost">
   <observer name="bt_add_coupon" instance="BT\Connect\Observer\TrackCoupon"/>
</event>
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost">
   <observer name="bt_add_coupon" instance="BT\Connect\Observer\TrackCoupon"/>
</event>
```

Comment: controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost and controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost actually worked. Not sure why were these not working earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` and **controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost** actually worked.

Not sure why were these not working earlier.

Comment: Doesnt work on Magento 2.3.0. Any idea what event might work on 2.3.0?

Comment: This is not working on Magento 2.3.x. @Jiyaad.D do you got any solution?

Comment: @VinothS I used interceptors instead - \Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement::beforeSet

Comment: @Jiyaad.D, pls update your answer of interceptors.

Comment: This will work only when the coupon code is applied and not for those,  which are auto-applied without the code.